# DropdownList populated with SelectList ignores selectedValueProperty

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hello I created a `SelectList` :

```
ViewBag.RoleId = new SelectList(unitOfWork.roleRepository.Get(), "Id", "RoleName", user.RoleId);
```

As you can see The `SelectedValue` property is set for this `SelectList`.

I'm binding it to `DropDownList` like in this sample:

```
@Html.DropDownList("RoleId", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

List is populated but selected value is always first value in the list instead of `user.RoleId` from controller.
How to modify initialization of the Html helper to make it work?

Comment: You need to set the object that should be selected as the 4th parameter. Currently, you're specifying the value of one of its properties. Try something like: `ViewBag.RoleId = new SelectList(unitOfWork.roleRepository.Get(), "Id", "RoleName", unitOfWork.roleRepository.Get().Where(x=>x.Id == user.RoleId).FirstOrDefault());`.

Comment: I just needed to need to: `var z= unitOfWork.roleRepository.Get().Where(x=>x.Id == user.RoleId).FirstOrDefault()` and then: `ViewBag.RoleId = new SelectList(unitOfWork.roleRepository.Get(), "Id", "RoleName", z.Id)` Thanks. Put it as an answer and I'll +1 and accept

Comment: I've edited my answer so that it doesn't query the repository twice. It's just a tweak but it makes a great improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SelectList` constructor expects the object to be selected as the 4th parameter. This object cannot be selected automatically in the constructor by specifying the value of one of its properties. The correct version is this:

```
var data = unitOfWork.roleRepository.Get();
ViewBag.RoleId = new SelectList(data, 
                 "Id", 
                 "RoleName",
                 data.Where(x => x.Id == user.RoleId).FirstOrDefault());
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind the dropdownlist as :

```
@Html.DropDownList("Id", (SelectList)ViewBag.RoleId, "Select Item", new { @class = "form-control" })
```